# Anonymous api call, baseAddress is null at Frontend

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#unauthenticated-or-unauthorized-web-api-requests-in-an-app-with-a-secure-default-client) to get some of my pages to access the API anonymously.

Tech:

- Net7
- Blazor
- Identity for auth.

My code:

**(Program.cs)**

```
 builder.Services.AddHttpClient("NoAuthenticationClient", httpClient =>
 httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7295/"));
```

Btw, I cannot use `new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)` as suggested in some places, I get:

> CS1061 'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).'

Did they move it elsewhere in NET7?

**(Index.razor)**

```
var NoAuthenticationClientWrng = ClientFactory.CreateClient("FakeClient"); //NOT defined at server program.cs
var NoAuthenticationClient = ClientFactory.CreateClient("NoAuthenticationClient"); //defined at server program.cs

var result = await NoAuthenticationClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Things>>("api/MyController/GetList");
```

`NoAuthenticationClientWrng` & `NoAuthenticationClient` look the same to me, I guess `ClientFactory.CreateClient` cannot retrieve the registered "NoAuthenticationClient". The baseAddress property is null in both cases.

The code returns:

> "An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be
> an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set"

when we consume.

If i add these two lines before consuming:

```
var NoAuthenticationClientWrng = ClientFactory.CreateClient("FakeClient"); //NOT defined at server program.cs
var NoAuthenticationClient = ClientFactory.CreateClient("NoAuthenticationClient"); //defined at server program.cs

var str = HostEnvironment.BaseAddress; //needs @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
        NoAuthenticationClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(str);

var result = await NoAuthenticationClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Things>>("api/MyController/GetList");
```

It works wo a logged user.

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb. 10 minutes after asking this question I found what was wrong.
You have to add the **(Program.cs)** code block in the client project NOT the server project.

It doesn't help both projects have a Program.cs